# What does this flow mean? (SDN)

Tags: sdn, openflow

```
mininet> dpctl dump-flows -O OpenFlow13
*** s1 ----------------------------------------------------------------
OFPST_FLOW reply (OF1.3) (xid=0x2):
cookie=0x0, duration=106.605s, table=0, n_packets=6, n_bytes=420, priority=0
actions=CONTROLLER:65509
mininet>
```

So this is the flow in an SDN switch (s1) after initially starting the controller and switch, but what is the prupose of this flow exactly? I don't quite understand it

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is the default flow that sends all packets to the controller. The controller can then install new flows, or process the packets via PACKET_OUT messages.

I believe that if you use the `-m` or `--more` argument it will show you that it is actually a flow that matches all fields wildcarded. This is omitted by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with the concept of forwarding table in conventional networking. 'Flows' has a similar role in software defined networks.

The switch under use appears to be OVS. OVS is a software switch with SDN capabilities. Thus you can instruct the switch what action to perform in a given situation. For instance:

```
Check destination mac address ; if mac address = aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff ; output interface is 1
```

This is an example of adding a flow to the switch.

In your show command the n_packets and n_bytes denote how many packets/bytes are effected by this flow.

you can think of `flow` as a rule based on which the OVS will forward packets.